# Convert Data Accelerometer in Degree

Tags: ios, accelerometer

i want convert de data acceler in degree.
but i don't know the code (objective c) very well. Somebody help me to realize this?
i need the see the degree and not the Accelerometer data!
i've this:

```
#import "APLGraphViewController.h"
#import "APLGraphView.h"
#import "APLAppDelegate.h"
#import "math.h"
@interface APLGraphViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *xLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *yLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *zLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *updateIntervalSlider;
@end
@implementation APLGraphViewController
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.updateIntervalSlider.value = 0.0f;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self startUpdatesWithSliderValue:(int)(self.updateIntervalSlider.value * 100)];
}
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self stopUpdates];
}
 #pragma mark - Responding to events
- (IBAction)takeSliderValueFrom:(UISlider *)sender
{
    [self startUpdatesWithSliderValue:(int)(sender.value * 100)];
}
- (void)setLabelValueX:(double)x y:(double)y z:(double)z
{
    self.xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x: %f", x];
    self.yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"y: %f", y];
    self.zLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"z: %f", z];
}
- (void)setLabelValueRoll:(double)roll pitch:(double)pitch yaw:(double)yaw
{
    self.xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"roll: %f", roll];
    self.yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pitch: %f", pitch];
    self.zLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yaw: %f", yaw];
}
#pragma mark - Update methods stub implementations
- (void)startUpdatesWithSliderValue:(int)sliderValue
{
    return;
}
- (void)stopUpdates
{
    return;
} 
@end
```

how can i obtain the degrees?

thanks

Comment: Doesn't seems to be related with XCode. Seems more like a mathematical issue than an Objective-C knowledge.

Comment: can be, I would use the function "atan2 ()," No, but I could implement it properly, you know, help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The accelerometer measures linear acceleration, not angular rotation. It sounds to me like you want gyroscope data (yaw, pitch and roll) not accelerometer data. Take a look at the docs for the CMDeviceMotion class. It gives rates of rotation along 3 axes.

Comment: sorry but no!I want to use the Z-axis accelerometer to measure the values ​​it gives me in degrees, lika a bobble level...

Comment: @user3119558 `CMAcceleration` is in `g` and `CMRotationRate` is in `radians`. Which one do you need? Do you ever read class references?

Comment: Ok but if i read tha acc data i want the degree on axis for know the inclination of device..

Comment: Then you will need to use trigonometry. You can use the x and y components to determine the angle. I probably can’t give you a code sample, because it is doing to depend on which axes you need depending on what your app is trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so you want to use the accelerometer to figure out which way is down, correct? That would let you figure out the orientation of the device, but not it's rotation around the "down" axis.